# Get first and last primary key values from SQLlite db table in Java?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to create methods for my DatabaseHandler class in Java to get the minimum and maximum row IDs from a single table in my database. I'm new to SQLite (working with Android) so I'm not sure what to do from here:

```
public int getMaxId() {
    String countQuery = "SELECT last_insert_rowid() FROM " + TABLE_RESOURCES;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
    int maxId = <SOMETHING>
    return maxId;
}
```

(I assume I could just change the sql query to 'first_insert_rowid()' for the first row ID - but how do I get and return that int?)

More background info: My table is constantly being written to and deleted from, so row IDs sometimes go like '2,3,4,5,8,9,11,13', and so on - and I'm running a for loop starting at the lowest row id available and going all the way to the highest, and ignoring empty spaces.

EDIT: Based on the answers, something like this? Only it gives a CursorOutOfBoundsException...

```
public int getMaxId() {
    String countQuery = "SELECT MAX(rowid) FROM " + TABLE_RESOURCES;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
    int maxId = 0;
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        maxId = cursor.getInt(0);
        return maxId;
    } else
    {
        return maxId;
    }

}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11515165/sqlite3-select-min-max-together-is-much-slower-than-select-them-separately

Comment: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: DESC (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM resources id ORDER BY DESC LIMIT 1  ... I think there's an error in the syntax... but thank you! This looks like it's very close to working now...

Comment: simply write String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM tablename columnname ORDER BY ASC LIMIT 1";

Comment: String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM resources id ORDER BY DESC LIMIT 1";  --- still comes up with 'no such column: DESC'...

Comment: Solved it! I needed to specify ORDER BY id DESC...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use  Order by and LIMIT 1.

ID Order by ASC LIMIT 1 will give you minimum and ID Order by DESC LIMIT 1 will give maximum

```
 public int  getMinId(){
    int minId = null;
    String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_RESOURCES + " " + KEY_ID +" ORDER BY ASC LIMIT 1";

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery,null);

    cursor.moveToFirst();
    if(cursor.getCount() > 0){

        minId= cursor.getInt(0);

    }
    cursor.close();
    db.close();

    return minId;
}
```

Comment: That could work! But how do I actually get the maxId integer out of the cursor?

Answer (score 0):

Use `MIN(rowid)` and `MAX(rowid)` instead of `last_insert_rowid()` to get the min and max values for rowid in a table.

Use something like

```
if (c.moveToFirst()) {
    int maxId = cursor.getInt(0);
}
```

to get a value from a cursor's first row where `0` is the column index you're interested in.

Also, Android's built-in database engine is SQLite and not MySQL.

Comment: I updated my post with your modifications - something like that? I get  a CursorIndexOutOfBounds Exception...